# Maple solving inequalities within a range

Tags: math-software, maple

I have no troubles to solve an inequality using this command:

```
solve(df(x) > 0, x)
```

However, I need to solve it within a specified range (-1..1). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

The `solve` command can handle multiple inequalities and equations. Write your range as inequality restrictions on your variable. Input either a set `{}` or a list `[]`. Example:

```
ineq := cos(x)>1/2;
myrange := x > 2*Pi, x<4*Pi;
solve({ineq,myrange},x);
```

Output:
$$\left\{ x<\frac73\,\pi ,2\,\pi <x \right\}, \left\{ x<4\,\pi ,\frac{11}3\,\pi <x \right\} $$